# Advanced kibana / elasticsearch devtools queries

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm querying my index in the following way:

```
GET INDEX/_count?q=KEY:VALUE
```

I want to get data on a list of values, so I run it multiple times:

```
GET INDEX/_count?q=KEY:VALUE0
GET INDEX/_count?q=KEY:VALUE1
GET INDEX/_count?q=KEY:VALUE2
```

Additionally, I want to check if the key exists. These options are available in the Discover window, but here I don't know how to access them...

What I eventually want: Query a specific index [I] and count (and, if possible, get advanced stats such as size of the total docs searched) all docs with specific key [K] existing, or having a value out of list of values (and, if possible, do that with regex). Added to that, I want the search / count to be between specific dates. I know how to do so in the Discover window, but Discover have 2 problems:

1. Gives the actual doc (too heavy, I only want size and count)
2. Involves GUI

To summarize, I have a few difficulties:

1. How to add size to the DevToools' count
2. How to count / search up to one month past
3. How to find if a key exists (e.g.  `GET I/_count?K:exists` ?)
4. How to find if value is one of list of allowed values (e.g.  `GET I/_count?K=x || K=y || K2=z`
5. How to describe value in regex (e.g. `GET I/_count?K=abc*`)
6. After count / search is done, how to delete said docs (Just replace GET with DELETE?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started:

```
GET INDEX/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "range": {
            "dateField": {
              "gte": "now-1M"
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "bool": {
            "filter": {
              "exists": {
                "field": "K"
              }
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "query_string": {
            "query": "K:(x OR y) OR K2:z"
          }
        },
        {
          "regexp": {
            "K": "abc*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Alternatively, you can switch `must` to `should`, thereby matching *either* of those subqueries.

After this, replace `_search` with `_delete_by_query` and you're good to go.

Comment: Will try it ASAP. Thanks!

Comment: how to add negation? "not exists"? and also, what the "filter" kw is used for?

Comment: Not exists: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html#find-docs-null-values. You don't actually need `filter` in this case -- it's similar to `must` but doesn't affect scoring: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html#query-dsl-bool-query